# Jquery remove div of previous selection and append current selection to allow only one selection per row using buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have The following code with buttons that append selections to the "cart" div on click

In The first Script, Its function is to allow only one selection per row
whenever multiple buttons in the same row are clicked.

In the second script, its function is to append the selections to the "cart" div
and remove if choice has been unselected.

The problem comes in when I click on multiple buttons in the same row, the first script seems to work just fine as in it de-actives the previous one and activates the current button clicked, the second script is supposed to remove the previous selection in the same row and update the new selection for the current button that is active

How do I get to edit my second script to cater for this functionality?

```
<body style ="margin:10px;">


  <div class="cart">
  
    <div id="box" class="boxlit"></div><br>
  
  </div>


  <table id="Table1" class="Fixtures-Table">


    <thead class="disnon">
      <tr>   
          <th>League</th>
          <th>Home [1]</th>
          <th>Draw [x]</th>
          <th>Away [2]</th>
          <th>Kickoff</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>


  <tr class="items" style="display: table-row;">
            
    <td class="addItem">Almagro-Temperley</td> 
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="3" value="1.95" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="4" value="2.95" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="5" value="3.90" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="date">8/1/2022 8:00:00 PM</td> 
    
  </tr>

  <tr class="items" style="display: table-row;">
              
    <td class="addItem">Guillermo Brown-Santamarina</td> 
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="6" value="1.65" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="7" value="3.25" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="8" value="5.10" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="date">8/1/2022 8:00:00 PM</td> 
    
  </tr>

  <tr class="items" style="display: table-row;">
              
    <td class="addItem">Nueva Chicago-CSD Flandria</td> 
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="9" value="2.25" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="10" value="2.85" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="11" value="3.15" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="date">8/1/2022 8:00:00 PM</td> 
    
  </tr>

</table>


</body>

</html>
```

In this script, Its function is to allow only one selection per row
whenever multiple buttons in the same row are clicked.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.decimals').click(function() { 

if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {

$(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');

$(this).removeClass('active');

} else {

$(this).closest('tr').find('.decimals').not(this)

.removeClass('active').attr('data-selected', 'false');

$(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');

$(this).addClass('active');

}

});
});

</script>
```

In this script, its function is to append the selections to the "cart" div
and remove if choice has been unselected.

its supposed to remove the previous selection in the same row and append or update the new selection for the current button that is active

```
<script>


  let $th = $('#Table1 thead th');
  
  $(".decimals").on('click', e => {
    
  let $btn = $(e.target);
  let $option = $(`.box[data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}"]`);
  
  let $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
  let selectionIndex = $btn.closest('td').index();
  
  let kickoff = $tr.find('td:last').text().trim();
  let match = $tr.find('td:first').text().trim();
  
  let result = $th.eq(selectionIndex).text().trim();
  let value = $btn.val();
  
  if ($option.length){
  $option.remove();
  
  return;
  }
  
  $("#box").append(`<div class="box" data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}">${match}<br>${result}<div class="crtTotal">${value}</div><input type="hidden" name="kickoff[]" value="${kickoff}"/><input type="hidden" name="match[]" value="${match}"/><input type="hidden" name="result[]" value="${result}" readonly/><input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="${value}"/></div>`);
  
  
  });
  
  
  </script>
```

```
.decimals {
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 2px solid #0e1516;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.decimals:hover {
     background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.active,
.active:hover {

    background: rgb(161, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: rgb(156, 0, 0);
    
}
```

Comment: This is what radio buttons are for.

Comment: Anybody to please help!!

Comment: You seem to have appended an "active" class and have forgotten to remove it in the event of selecting another choice in the same row. Try doing a .removeClass('active') on the previously selected item.

Comment: How exactly do I do this? please reply as an answer, I will surely mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set timeout was causing the issue. I adjusted it in the following code:

When changing the stake it is also updating now I added a small line.

```js
let $th = $('#Table1 thead th');

$('.decimals').click(function(e) { 

let $btn = $(e.target);
  let $option = $(`.box[data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}"]`);
  
  let $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
  let selectionIndex = $btn.closest('td').index();
  
  let kickoff = $tr.find('td:last').text().trim();
  let match = $tr.find('td:first').text().trim();
  
  let result = $th.eq(selectionIndex).text().trim();
  let value = $btn.val();

var knowit = $(this).closest('.items').find('.addItem').text();

var radiovalue = $(this).attr('value');


if ($('.boxlit .box:contains("'+knowit+'")').length < 1) {


  $("#box").append(`<div class="box" data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}">${match}<br><span>${result}</span><div class="crtTotal">${value}</div><input type="hidden" name="kickoff[]" value="${kickoff}"/><input type="hidden" name="match[]" value="${match}"/><input type="hidden" name="result[]" value="${result}" readonly/><input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="${value}"/></div>`);}

else if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
$('.boxlit .box:contains("'+knowit+'")').remove()
}


else {
$('.boxlit .box:contains("'+knowit+'") .crtTotal').text(radiovalue);

$('.boxlit .box:contains("'+knowit+'") span').text(result);
}

})
```

```css
.decimals {
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 2px solid #0e1516;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.decimals:hover {
     background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.active,
.active:hover {

    background: rgb(161, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: rgb(156, 0, 0);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style ="margin:10px;">


  <div class="cart">
  
    <div id="box" class="boxlit"></div><br>

<div class="shift">

  <div>Total Odds: <b id="ct1">0.00</b></div><br>

  <div>(N$)Stake: <input id="stake" type ="number" name="stake[]" value="5"> NAD</div><br>

  <div>Payout: N$ <b id="payout">0.00</b></div>

  <input class="bet1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Bet">

</div>
  
  </div>


  <table id="Table1" class="Fixtures-Table">


    <thead class="disnon">
      <tr>   
          <th>League</th>
          <th>Home [1]</th>
          <th>Draw [x]</th>
          <th>Away [2]</th>
          <th>Kickoff</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>


  <tr class="items" style="display: table-row;">
            
    <td class="addItem">Almagro-Temperley</td> 
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="3" value="1.95" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="4" value="2.95" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="5" value="3.90" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="date">8/1/2022 8:00:00 PM</td> 
    
  </tr>

  <tr class="items" style="display: table-row;">
              
    <td class="addItem">Guillermo Brown-Santamarina</td> 
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="6" value="1.65" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="7" value="3.25" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="8" value="5.10" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="date">8/1/2022 8:00:00 PM</td> 
    
  </tr>

  <tr class="items" style="display: table-row;">
              
    <td class="addItem">Nueva Chicago-CSD Flandria</td> 
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="9" value="2.25" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="10" value="2.85" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="11" value="3.15" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="date">8/1/2022 8:00:00 PM</td> 
    
  </tr>

</table>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.decimals').click(function() { 

if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {

$(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');

$(this).removeClass('active');

} else {

$(this).closest('tr').find('.decimals').not(this)

.removeClass('active').attr('data-selected', 'false');

$(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');

$(this).addClass('active');

}

});
});

</script>



<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.decimals').click(function(e) { 
 updateoddsnpayout();
})

$('body').on('change', '#stake', function(e){
 updateoddsnpayout();
})

var updateoddsnpayout =  function(e) {
let values = $('.crtTotal').map((i, el) => parseFloat(el.textContent)).get();
let total = values.reduce((a, b) => a * b, values.length > 0 ? 1 : 0);
let eq = 0
let tot = eq += total


$('#ct1').text(tot.toFixed(2)).val()
$('#todds').val(tot.toFixed(2)).val()


var z = 0
var x = parseFloat($('#ct1').text()?? 0);
var y = parseFloat($('#stake').val()?? 0);
var net = z + x * y
$("#payout").text(net.toFixed(2)).val();
$("#inp").val(net.toFixed(2)).val();

}
})


</script>







</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the the issue was with removing the existing appended cart div. I did something hoping it would fix your issue.
But it may be better to just updates the values as in my code flickering occurs.

```js
let $th = $('#Table1 thead th');

$('.decimals').click(function(e) { 

let $btn = $(e.target);
  let $option = $(`.box[data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}"]`);
  
  let $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
  let selectionIndex = $btn.closest('td').index();
  
  let kickoff = $tr.find('td:last').text().trim();
  let match = $tr.find('td:first').text().trim();
  
  let result = $th.eq(selectionIndex).text().trim();
  let value = $btn.val();

var knowit = $(this).closest('.items').find('.addItem').text();

var radiovalue = $(this).attr('value');


if ($('.boxlit .box:contains("'+knowit+'")').length < 1) {

setTimeout ( function () { 
  $("#box").append(`<div class="box" data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}">${match}<br><span>${result}</span><div class="crtTotal">${value}</div><input type="hidden" name="kickoff[]" value="${kickoff}"/><input type="hidden" name="match[]" value="${match}"/><input type="hidden" name="result[]" value="${result}" readonly/><input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="${value}"/></div>`); },0) }

else if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
$('.boxlit .box:contains("'+knowit+'")').remove()
}


else {
$('.boxlit .box:contains("'+knowit+'") .crtTotal').text(radiovalue);

$('.boxlit .box:contains("'+knowit+'") span').text(result);
}

})
```

```css
.decimals {
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 2px solid #0e1516;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.decimals:hover {
     background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.active,
.active:hover {

    background: rgb(161, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: rgb(156, 0, 0);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style ="margin:10px;">


  <div class="cart">
  
    <div id="box" class="boxlit"></div><br>
  
  </div>


  <table id="Table1" class="Fixtures-Table">


    <thead class="disnon">
      <tr>   
          <th>League</th>
          <th>Home [1]</th>
          <th>Draw [x]</th>
          <th>Away [2]</th>
          <th>Kickoff</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>


  <tr class="items" style="display: table-row;">
            
    <td class="addItem">Almagro-Temperley</td> 
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="3" value="1.95" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="4" value="2.95" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="5" value="3.90" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="date">8/1/2022 8:00:00 PM</td> 
    
  </tr>

  <tr class="items" style="display: table-row;">
              
    <td class="addItem">Guillermo Brown-Santamarina</td> 
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="6" value="1.65" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="7" value="3.25" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="8" value="5.10" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="date">8/1/2022 8:00:00 PM</td> 
    
  </tr>

  <tr class="items" style="display: table-row;">
              
    <td class="addItem">Nueva Chicago-CSD Flandria</td> 
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="9" value="2.25" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="10" value="2.85" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="bbox"><input type="button" class="decimals" id="11" value="3.15" data-selected="false"></td>
    <td id="date">8/1/2022 8:00:00 PM</td> 
    
  </tr>

</table>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.decimals').click(function() { 

if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {

$(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');

$(this).removeClass('active');

} else {

$(this).closest('tr').find('.decimals').not(this)

.removeClass('active').attr('data-selected', 'false');

$(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');

$(this).addClass('active');

}

});
});

</script>





</body>
```

Comment: Good , You're a genius!! yes! how do I get it to update instead of removing to avoid flickering?

Comment: I edited my answer, now it works without the flickering. If it resolved your issue I would appreciate if you upvoted the answer.

Comment: please check the new answer I posted, I am having a small issue, can you please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to add a section that calculates total odds and total payout to the cart using the reduce method and I'm having a small problem with the calculation when appending the first selection, It seems to only calculate after the second button click, whenever I click on another button, the total starts calculation on the second click, it feels like its one step back when It appends other selections

here is the code for the cart

```html
<div id="box" class="boxlit"></div><br>
  <div class="shift">
    <div>Total Odds: <b id="ct1">0.00</b></div><br>
    <div>(N$)Stake: <input id="stake" type ="number" name="stake[]" value="5"> NAD</div><br>
    <div>Payout: N$ <b id="payout">0.00</b></div>
    <input class="bet1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Bet">
</div>
```

This Is the code that calculates the total odds and payout of selections

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.decimals').click(function(e) { 
      let values = $('.crtTotal').map((i, el) => 
        parseFloat(el.textContent)).get();

      let total = values.reduce((a, b) => a * b, values.length > 0 ? 1 : 0);
      let eq = 0
      let tot = eq += total

      $('#ct1').text(tot.toFixed(2)).val()
      $('#todds').val(tot.toFixed(2)).val()


      var z = 0
      var x = parseFloat($('#ct1').text()?? 0);
      var y = parseFloat($('#stake').val()?? 0);
      var net = z + x * y
      $("#payout").text(net.toFixed(2)).val();
      $("#inp").val(net.toFixed(2)).val();
    })
  })
</script>
```

I tried tracking where the problem is coming from and it seems to be at the `setTimeout` section,

```js
setTimeout(function() { 
  $("#box").append(`<div class="box" data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}">${match}<br><span>${result}</span><div class="crtTotal">${value}</div></div>`);
},0)
```

It appends the values to the cart, how do I correct my code to calculate from the first button click?